# When is valid_contract column in tx table true and a contract?

Tags: cardano-node, cardano-db-sync

In the schema descriptions for cardano-db-sync, the valid_contract column description is as follows (link below):

"False if the contract is invalid. True if the contract is valid or there is no contract."

If TRUE, how can we know the difference between a tx that is using a contract and one that is simply me moving an asset from one wallet to another?

https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/blob/master/doc/schema.md

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you can just look at the `script_size` field of the `tx` table. If that field it greater than zero there is a script.

Comment: Thank you! I will add that as a filter and see what I see.